# Linq to XML using descendant to get values

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customers xmlns="http://example.com/ns/" si="0" records="2">
  <customer id="123456789">
    <dob>2017-12-10T16:22:27.033Z</dob>
    <location>
      <number>444555666777</number>
    </location>
    <link rel="self" href="http://example.com" />
  </customer>
  <customer id="987654321">
    <dob>2017-12-11T17:00:00.033Z</dob>
    <location>
      <number>555666999888</number>
    </location>
    <link rel="self" href="http://example.com" />
  </customer>
  <link rel="self" href="http://example.com" />
</customers>
```

I managed to query the file using

```
Dim X As XElement = Xelement.Load("C:\XMLFile1.xml")
Dim Customers As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = Xelement.Elements()

' Read the entire XML
For Each c In Customers
    Console.WriteLine(c)
Next
```

The target was to get all the number values (under location) but i thought to go one step further and see if i could get this element in one line rather than having a for each loop (not sure if this is possible at all either?). So i changed the code to

```
Dim xd As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\XMLFile1.xml")
Dim xe As XElement = Xd.Root
Dim nums As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe.Descendants.Where(Function(x) x.Element("number").Value)
'Dim nums As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe.Descendants.Where(Function(x) x.Element("location").Element("number").Value)
```

This comes back as null/nothing. I have tried different variations, mixing Elements with Descendants and adding multiple Selects but i think i need a working example to really understand what is going on and where im making a mistake. Seeing examples on the web didnt really help as i think i ended up confusing myself.

I read a few articles but some are pointing to adding a namespace but i dont really want to go down that avenue until i understand whats going and if i really need it or not?

Comment: This is `vb`, not `c#`. Please don't add tags that are not related to your question.

Comment: Yes i know, but i do both C# and VB .Net and though there are similarities in syntax, i'm sure if C# code was posted as an answer i could convert it to VB.Net easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important thing to note is that your XML has [*default namespace*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/757cbs7s(v=vs.71).aspx), declared at the root element, which URI is `"http://example.com/ns/"`. Based on the definition of default namespace, the root element along with all descendant elements without prefix in your XML are belong to this namespace, hence we need to use `XNamespace` combined with element's local-name to properly reference element in namespace :

```
Dim ns As XNamespace = "http://example.com/ns/"
Dim numbers As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xe.Descendants(ns+"number")
For Each number As XElement In numbers
    Console.WriteLine(number.Value)
Next
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NCgHkS)</kbd>**

Comment: Yes that did it. Just one other point i managed to get the namespace without coding it into a string by using Dim ns As XNamespace = xe.GetDefaultNamespace, hopefully this should be fine to use.